# create unique nested objects dynamically

Tags: javascript

I need to create unique objects(Route) for the ***my*** variable's ***routes*** property. And this has to be done in a *loop*.

Please check out my code blow or http://jsfiddle.net/2gk36mvo/ to have a more clear image about my problem.

**html**

```
<input type="button" value="ss" onclick="initialize();">
```

**javascript**

```
var my={
        routes:{}
};

function Route(points)
{
    this.points = points;
    return this;
};

function getRoutes(routes){
    var result = [];
    for (var prop in my.routes) {
        result.push(prop);
    }
    return result.toString();
}

function initialize()
{
    // create and add objects manually
    my.routes.r0 = new Route("blabla0");
    my.routes.r1 = new Route("blabla1");
    alert(getRoutes(my.routes)); // gives 'r0,r1'

    // clear the routes for the dynamic test
    my.routes = {};

    // create and add objects dynamically
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        //???????????? create and and add the new Route objects
    }
    alert(getRoutes(my.routes)); // must give the same result as above 'r0,r1'
}
```

Comment: `my.routes['r'+i] = new Route('blahhh');` inside for loop. Also use `if(my.routes.hasOwnProperty(prop))` in `getRoutes()` function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jLqm77au/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cackharot states in his comment, you need to have code similar to this in your for loop:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
 {
    my.routes["r"+i] =  new Route("blahbla"+i);
    console.log(my.routes);
 }
```